# Return Invoice Based on Invoice Items (INNER JOIN)

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 tables in SQL Server: Invoice and InvoiceItem. Both tables have an InvoiceID column and the InvoiceItem table has an ItemID column.

What I need is a query that I can run to return an invoice if the InvoiceItems have exactly the ItemID's specified.

Example:

```
Invoice.InvoiceID = 1

InvoiceItem.InvoiceItemID = 1
InvoiceItem.InvoiceID = 1
InvoiceItem.ItemID = 1

InvoiceItem.InvoiceItemID = 2
InvoiceItem.InvoiceID = 1
InvoiceItem.ItemID = 2
```

I need to query for any invoices that have EXACTLY 2 line items, one with an ItemID of 1 and one with an ItemID of 2.

I thought an INNER JOIN with an "IN" statement might get me there, but it returns more than just the one invoice. The following returns any invoice that has an ItemID of 1 or 2. It's kind of like I want an "and" instead of an "or" in the "IN".

```
SELECT InvoiceID FROM Invoice i INNER JOIN InvoiceItem ii ON i.InvoiceID = ii.InvoiceID WHERE ii.ItemID IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> And instead of Or in the IN

I understand what you mean but it wouldn't work because you're thinking across multiple rows, which are like different instances of the same kind of item. If you were looking for a row where itemid = 1 and itemid = 2 you'd never get anything because no single row satisfies this

Instead you can look at the whole collection of rows for a particular invoice, and look at them in aggregation. What you're effectively saying is "I want invoice ids where the number of detail lines is two, the lowest item ID is 1 and the highest is 2" - this is "looking across multiple rows" and selecting aggregate attributes:

```
SELECT InvoiceID 
FROM InvoiceItems 
GROUP BY InvoiceID 
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) = 2 AND 
  MIN(ItemId) = 1 AND 
  MAX(ItemID) = 2
```

Notes:

- you can omit the count check if InvoiceID,ItemID is unique
- put this into a subquery and join in the Invoices table afterwards, if you want info from it

You asked for any variable number of items here's a technique for it:

```
SELECT InvoiceID 
FROM InvoiceItems 
GROUP BY InvoiceID 
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE ItemID 
    WHEN 9 THEN 2 
    WHEN 38 THEN 4 
    WHEN 483 THEN 8 
    ELSE 1 END
  ) = 14 AND 
  COUNT(*) = 3
```

By converting your numbers to 2,4 or 8 and mandating 3 items, there's only one way to get to 14..

Comment: This assumes always 2 item lines and the ItemID is 1 and 2. That was just my example. What if the required ItemIDs were 9, 38, and 483? In other words, a variable number of items and a variety of IDs.

Comment: Your "example" looked like a specification.. I'll make an edit